# Jquery hide row from table on button press

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following table code:

```
echo "<table border='1'>
        <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products where updated_account_ID='$aktiv'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['code'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . "<button name='code' value='".$row['code'] ."'>Delete</button></td>";

echo "</tr>";
```

I would like to use jquery to hide or delete the specified row after pressing the "Delete" button which also deletes the record from the database. Could someone be so kind and help be do it?
Thank you!

Comment: you will have to do it using ajax

Comment: Ohh i see, could you please tell me how to do whit that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

jQUERY :

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
var product_id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('data-product-id');
$(this).parents('tr').remove();
$.ajax({
    url: "remove-record.php",
    data: product_id,
    type: "post",
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

});

PHP FILE :

```
echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Price</th>
    </tr>";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM products where updated_account_ID='$aktiv'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<tr data-product-id='".$row['id']."'>";
echo "<td>" . $row['code'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['price'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<button name='code' value='".$row['code'] ."'>Delete</button
</td>";

echo "</tr>";
```

remove-record.php :

```
$product_id = $_POST['data'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id=product_id";
echo json_encode('Record deleted');
```

Comment: Thank you! Code working fine!

Comment: EDIT: unfortunately this does not work

Comment: what is the issue?
have you debug code, where it fails?

Comment: nothing fails, no error but id does nothing :S

Comment: try to debug it,
add console.log() in click function
see if request is send from ajax to remove-record.php

or else add your code on jsfiddle